# jQuery AJAX POST; Not posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm fairly certain the issue I'm having is related to the jQuery's `$.ajax({...});` function . When printing the array in PHP i get `Notice: Undefined index`.

I'd sincerely appreciate it if i could get some advice here.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {
         var platform_var =  $('input[name="platform"]').val();
         var bandwidth_var = $("#bandwidth-widget").val();
         alert(bandwidth_var); // Returns the array as an alert.
         $.ajax({
            url:    "index.php",
            type:   "POST",
            data:   {
                        platform_var: platform_var,
                        bandwidth_var: bandwidth_var
                        }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<?php 
print_r($_POST['platform_var']);
?>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KDsX8/) (w/o PHP)

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($_POST);`? If so, what does it output?

Comment: I just tried it, it's printing the same as `print_r($_POST['platform'])`.

Comment: Does it only have one element within it? Could you also do a `print_r($_REQUEST);`, just to rule out whether the data isn't using _POST?

Comment: Try adding: `cache: false` after the ajax `type` line, and re-running the data. So your JS should look like: `type: $(this).attr('method'), cache: false, data: `... etc

Comment: The issue can't be related to the `type:` as i just tried `type:'POST'` and that didn't work either. I'll try the `cache: false` now.

Comment: `cache: false` hasn't made a difference either :(. I have update the question to show the code as it is now.

Comment: Could you please show us the html of the form?

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle, thanks for the help mate, cant stress how much i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have two problems in your code:

1. The selector is wrong - you're searching for an input with the `name` attribute which equals to `platform` and in the html you have an array input with the name `platform[]`. Therefore it will not find any matching inputs, which is why the `var platform_var` is `undefined` or `null`.
2. To fetch the checked checkboxes, you need to add `:checked` to the selector, otherwise jQuery will return all of the checkboxes regardless of their checkbox status.

To fix this, simply change

```
var platform_var =  $('input[name="platform"]').val();
```

to

```
var platform_var =  $('input[name="platform[]"]:checked').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Also, have in mind that in your php script, the `$_POST['platform']` variable will be an array.

I would advice you to have a look at the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to further understand how the selectors work.

Here is the edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fH49/1/).

Edit: 
I've code I've added below confirms that the code in the fiddle is working fine. Apparently you are having trouble with your own php code rather than your JavaScript.
I believe you should sit down and check your code.

```
<?php
// Save everything here in a file called "test.php"

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}

?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.hostingarchive.com/wp-content/themes/My-theme/assets/styles/jquery.selectBox.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.hostingarchive.com/wp-content/themes/My-theme/assets/styles/jquery.nouislider.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hostingarchive.com/wp-content/themes/My-theme/assets/scripts/jquery.selectBox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hostingarchive.com/wp-content/themes/My-theme/assets/scripts/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.cmp-select').selectBox();

            $("#price-widget").noUiSlider({
                range: [5, 150], start: [5, 75], step: [5], connect: true, direction: 'ltr', serialization: {
                    mark: '.', resolution: 1, to: [
                        [$("#low-price"), 'html'],
                        [$('#high-price'), 'html']
                    ]
                }
            });

            $("#bandwidth-widget").noUiSlider({
                range: [0, 2000], start: [10, 1000], step: [10], connect: true, direction: 'ltr', serialization: {
                    mark: '.', resolution: 1, to: [
                        [$("#low-bandwidth"), 'html'],
                        [$('#high-bandwidth'), 'html']
                    ]
                }
            });

            $("#submit").click(function () {
                var platform_var = $('input[name="platform[]"]:checked').map(function () {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();
                var bandwidth_var = $("#bandwidth-widget").val();
                alert(bandwidth_var);
                console.log(platform_var);
                console.log(bandwidth_var);

                $.ajax({
                    url : "test.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        platform_var : platform_var,
                        bandwidth_var: bandwidth_var
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="compare">
    <h3>Platform</h3>
    <input name="platform[]" type="checkbox" value="shared" checked="checked">Shared</input>
    <input name="platform[]" type="checkbox" value="dedicated">Dedicated</input>
    <input name="platform[]" type="checkbox" value="cdn">CDN</input>
    <input name="platform[]" type="checkbox" value="vps">VPS</input>
    <input name="platform[]" type="checkbox" value="vds">VDS</input>

    <h3>Bandwidth</h3>

    <div id="bandwidth-slide">
        <p class="inline-block"><span id="low-bandwidth"></span><span><small>GB</small></span></p>
        <div class="inline-block" id="bandwidth-widget"></div>
        <p class="inline-block"><span id="high-bandwidth"></span><span><small>GB</small></span></p>
    </div>

    <h3>Price</h3>

    <div id="pricing-slide" class="clearfix">
        <p class="inline-block">$<span id="low-price"></span></p>

        <div class="inline-block" id="price-widget"></div>
        <p class="inline-block">$<span id="high-price"></span><span>/mo</span></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="enter">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man, i wrongly assumed `$('input[name="platform"]').val();` would pick up the array, woops. But this sadly doesn't explain why bandwidth_var wouldn't work either - or even a variable with a string attached to it :(

Comment: If you open up your browser console in the jsfiddle, then submit the form, you will see that in the sent request you have `bandwidth_var[] 10, bandwidth_var[] 1000, platform_var[] shared, platform_var[] cdn`. So both of these vars are arrays. You need to process them on the server side.

Comment: I see that too in the network tab in chrome, but, it is still returning undefined in PHP. I am using `if (isset($_POST['platform_var'])){
 print_r($_POST['platform_var']);
}`. What am i doing wrong? :-(

Comment: Also, weirdly on the preview section, it returns the array as it should, is this some sort of caching mechanism? I have a screenshot of what i mean [here](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/52f8c764ecbdb.jpg)

Comment: Without seeing the php code I can't say anything. My guess is you're trying to `print_r` at the end of the script, and you should have `print_r(...); exit()` in the if/else.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST)){
 print_r($_POST);
}
else{
 echo 'Variable is not set';
}`At the moment, this PHP is after the ajax code which posts the page, that couldn't be the problem could it?

Comment: I doubt this is the only thing you have in your `php` script and without a proper example of what's not working, nobody here at SO will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the values to the variables on document load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  platform_var =  $('input[name="platform"]').val();
  bandwidth_var = $("#bandwidth-widget").val();
});
```

**EDIT:** if the values are not instanciated on document load, you need to assign them when they actually have the correct value, just before you do the Ajax request.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#compare', function(e) {
     var platform_var =  $('input[name="platform"]').val();
     var bandwidth_var = $("#bandwidth-widget").val();
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: {
                    platform: platform_var,
                    bandwidth: bandwidth_var
                }
    });
});
```

Currently, you are assigning them before the values actually exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried that, but, to no avail I'm afraid. Also, the script was being loaded at the bottom of the page anyway, not sure i need it.

Comment: @JackWilliams I just updated my answer, you need to assign the values right before your ajax.

Comment: and of course add `var` before assigning values. `var platform_var = ...`. updated my answer.

Comment: Same result i'm afraid.

Comment: seems like you have some other problems then, without showing your markup I can't help you. Try posting a JSFiddle.

Comment: @JackWilliams do a `console.log($("#bandwidth-widget").val())` and see what that returns. If that returns the proper value, then you're probably having a cache problem - your browser has cached the request at some point and is returning the same response. The code of @Yani is valid and should be working.

Comment: It doesn't allow PHP though.

Comment: @tftd I just tried it in firefox, and now, both prints are returning undefined index.

Comment: If `$("#bandwidth-widget").val()` returns nothing in the browser, then it will submit nothing to the `PHP` script. So, apparently your element with id `bandwidth-widget` can't be reached. Are you sure it exists and is an input?

Comment: `console.log()` returned `Array[2]
0: "10"
1: "1000"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
 ` *But only when it's outside of the submit function.

Comment: @tftd. I've update my question, can you help me out? I still haven't found the problem :(